# ProcessReceivedMessage Error in MqttDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, libraries, mqtt, argumentexception

I am building a .NET IoT project that requires MQTT for communication. For the broker I use [GnatMQ](https://github.com/ppatierno/gnatmq) and for clients I use [MqttDotNet](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/MqttDotNet) (for mobile compatibility). The **client** library builds, connects, and sends messages fine but I get an error whenever the client’s *PublishArrivedDelegate* is triggered (i.e. message received event).

The error occurs on retained messages as well as standard received messages. The MqttDotNet error log is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R9jc7yxuegF3pq7pbDo8YudTBH-mH6VQ376zwk0hAuc/edit?usp=sharing).

Console output: [image]

It seems the error is captured in the QoSManager.cs on line 91:

```
else if (mess.QualityOfService == QoS.OnceAndOnceOnly)
{
     _responses.Add(mess.MessageID, new MqttPubrelMessage(mess.MessageID));
}
```

**NOTE:** I am using the raw libraries (as they are) without added code.

Has anyone tried these libraries and can maybe confirm that it worked for them without issues? Until then, I guess it's debugging till the extreme.

**Update 1:** The error only persists on subscribe with QoS level 2.

**Update 2:** The error can be prevented by adding a handle to prevent duplicates from being added to the hashtable, as pointed out by @hardillb . But this does not SOLVE the actual issue here.

The issue still persists on publish and subscribe with QOS 2. The problem is that the `onClientPublishedArrived` is being triggered exactly 3 times whenever a message gets received and exactly 2 times when a message get received as retained. NOTE that when I test this with [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com/try-out/) the issue is gone. The problem only persists when using the [GnatMQ](https://github.com/ppatierno/gnatmq) broker.

Comment: What is the _responses object?

Comment: @hardillb Its the name of the Hashtable instance.

Comment: From the update this sounds like GnatMQ's QOS2 implementation is broken and you should probably raise a defect with them

Comment: @hardlib Yes, I will try raise the issue there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to add duplicate keys to a Hashtable, this will be being caused by `mess.MessageID` returning the same value for multiple messages.

The C# implementation looks like it throws an exception rather replacing the original value with the new value.

If you just need a unique key for the Hashtable you could use something like the timestamp

Comment: That's correct. Duplicate keys are being added, but even stopping duplicate keys from being added does not solve the actual issue. The physical "onClientPublishedArrived" event sill triggers exactly three times with publish and subscribe QOS 2 only.